# Varying text per print

Tags: gimp

I'm looking at designing some invitations for an event and would like to be able to provide a list of names to gimp and have it generate multiple personalised outputs of the design, like a mail merge in something like MS Word would do.

Ideally this would be directly to a printer but to a series of saved files would be fine.

Is there any way of doing this in Gimp? If not, does anyone know of a similar program that could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such functionality in off-the-shelf Gimp, and I couldn't find an existing  script.

But IMHO, you have better make the background image in Gimp, insert it in some Office or LibreOffice document, and use the mail merge function.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll see how well that works, if not maybe look at writing a script.